# A Connect Wall to help you relax

Tags: word, pattern, connect-wall

The 16 words below may be separated into 4 groups.
Additionally, there is a word absent from the wall which can be placed in all four of those groups.

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **BEAN** | **BEE** | **BACK** | **CAN** |
| **EON** | **EYES** | **FLAG** | **HEART** |
| **INK** | **PEA** | **QUEUE** | **RANGE** |
| **RAY** | **SCONE** | **SEA** | **WINE** |

**Can you identify the four groups?**
**What new word can be placed in all four of those groups?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Four groups:

> **Bee**, **Sea**, **Pea**, **Queue**: Sounds like letter (B,C,P,Q)
>  **Ink**, **Ray**, **Back**, **Can**: Add 1 letter to make color (Pink, Gray, Black, Cyan)
>  **Bean**, **Wine**, **Flag**, **Eyes**: Red (Red Bean, Red Wine, Red Flag, Red Eyes)
>  **Eon**, **Heart**, **Scone**, **Range**: Move first letter to end to make new word (One, Earth, Cones, Anger)

Missing word:

> **Tea** (T, Teal, Red Tea, Eat)

Comment: Also, the missing word will help one to relax, maybe?